# Using the word „God“ in poems?

Tags: language, poetry

I wrote some poems in German about  religious issues and about other topics like friendship. I try to give the poems a good message and I also praise Allah (in German).

Is writing poems permissible at all? And can I use the word „Gott“, which is the German equivalent to the word „God“?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu 'Alaikum. No there is InshaAllah no problem at all with using God's name in poems a lot of the early Islamic scholars wrote poems about God and Islam or other things with God's name in it.